# Why is my code not running?

Tags: javascript

I'm simply trying to solve Euler problem #1, but nothing is coming up. Here's the code:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
        sum += i;
    }
}
alert(sum);
```

I have no library & onLoad settings.

Comment: Please make use of your developer console.

Answer (score 4):

You are declaring your variables wrong. You do not declare types in JavaScript:

```
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
    sum += i;
  }
}
alert(sum);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5DL3t/